# What does dd write, when it encounters a input/output error?

Tags: backup, hard-disk, dd, corruption

I have a drive that's on the verge of failing (C5 a C6 are triggered) so I decided to make another backup while I still can. For that, I'm using dd to another drive of the exact same model. As expected, I have some input/output errors, and I'd like to know, what dd does when it encounters errors. Does it just skip the sector and writes nothing? Or does it replace the data that was previously on the target drive with 0s?

Also, since I'm using 64K blocks, can I run dd at the location where the copy failed with a smaller block size to try to get a little bit more data out of it?

Comment: Don't use dd. Use ddrescue, which handles these read errors gracefully.

Comment: You get the program `ddrescue` by installing the package `gddrescue` (at least in Debian and Ubuntu). The info pages at `info ddrescue` are very useful. Please read them before starting to use the program.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, [GNU `ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is a way better tool for this use case. Let me answer your explicit questions about `dd` anyway.

> I'd like to know, what `dd` does when it encounters errors

It exits, unless `conv=noerror` was given, which makes the tool ignore *input* errors. Let's suppose `noerror` was given and an input error occurred. Then

> Does it just skip the sector and writes nothing? Or does it replace the data that was previously on the target drive with 0s?

It depends whether or not you used `conv=sync`. If you do, `dd` will pad every input block to the size of the `ibs=` buffer, appending null bytes. I *guess* if `ibs` equals the sector size of your source block device, then this will keep your output stream in sync with the input in case of read errors. But with wrong `ibs` it's very probable a read error will make streams get out of sync, like in [this excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690). It seems `iflag=fullblock` helps.

Additionally `sync` may make your output bigger than input, even when there are no read errors; this will happen if the last block hits EOF before `ibs` buffer gets full.

Note `noerror` and `sync` are [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html), `fullblock` is not.

> can I run `dd` at the location where the copy failed with a smaller block size to try to get a little bit more data out of it?

In theory -- yes. But this requires you to manually work with `skip=` and `seek=`, while still taking care of problems mentioned above. Don't forget you need to recalculate `skip` and `seek` to correspond to the new block size. It's possible, but you will soon wish to automate the process.

---

And now compare all these issues with GNU `ddrescue` default behavior:

- It skips read errors; it gets back to "suspicious" fragments later, trying to read them  in smaller and smaller chunks.
- It keeps proper offsets no matter what.